# BST or Hash Table?

Tags: python, c, data-structures, file-io

I have large text files upon which all kinds of operations need to be performed, mostly involving row by row validations.  The data are generally of a sales / transaction nature, and thus tend to contain a huge amount of redundant information across rows, such as customer names.  Iterating and manipulating this data has become such a common task that I'm writing a library in C that I hope to make available as a Python module.

In one test, I found that out of 1.3 million column values, only ~300,000 were unique.  Memory overhead is a concern, as our Python based web application could be handling simultaneous requests for large data sets.

My first attempt was to read in the file and insert each column value into a binary search tree.  If the value has never been seen before, memory is allocated to store the string, otherwise a pointer to the existing storage for that value is returned.  This works well for data sets of ~100,000 rows.  Much larger and everything grinds to a halt, and memory consumption skyrockets.  I assume the overhead of all those node pointers in the tree isn't helping, and using strcmp for the binary search becomes very painful.

This unsatisfactory performance leads me to believe I should invest in using a hash table instead.  This, however, raises another point -- I have no idea ahead of time how many records there are.  It could be 10, or ten million.  How do I strike the right balance of time / space to prevent resizing my hash table again and again?

What are the best data structure candidates in a situation like this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: why don't you move the data into a real database? It sounds a bit like you are reinventing one.

Comment: To a certain extent I can agree with that, but given all the requirements of the application, the non-RDBMS route made sense, and still does for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash table resizing *isn't* a concern unless you have a requirement that each insert into the table should take the same amount of time. As long as you always expand the hash table size by a constant factor (e.g. always increasing the size by 50%), the computational cost of adding an extra element is amortized `O(1)`. This means that `n` insertion operations (when `n` is large) will take an amount of time that is proportionate to `n` - however, the actual time per insertion may vary wildly (in practice, one of the insertions will be very slow while the others will be very fast, but the average of all operations is small). The reason for this is that when you insert an extra element that forces the table to expand from e.g. 1000000 to 1500000 elements, that insert will take a lot of time, but now you've bought yourself 500000 extremely fast future inserts before you need to resize again. In short, I'd definitely go for a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [incremental resizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Incremental_resizing) of your hash table.  In my current project, I keep track of the hash key size used in every bucket, and if that size is below the current key size of the table, then I rehash that bucket on an insert or lookup.  On a resizing of the hash table, the key size doubles (add an extra bit to the key) and in all the new buckets, I just add a pointer back to the appropriate bucket in the existing table.  So if `n` is the number of hash buckets, the hash expand code looks like:

```
n=n*2;
bucket=realloc(bucket, sizeof(bucket)*n);
for (i=0,j=n/2; j<n; i++,j++) {
  bucket[j]=bucket[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> library in C that I hope to make
>   available as a Python module

Python already has very efficient finely-tuned hash tables built in. I'd strongly suggest that you get your library/module working in Python first. Then check the speed. If that's not fast enough, profile it and remove any speed-humps that you find, perhaps by using Cython.

setup code:

```
shared_table = {}
string_sharer = shared_table.setdefault
```

scrunching each input row:

```
for i, field in enumerate(fields):
    fields[i] = string_sharer(field, field)
```

You may of course find after examining each column that some columns don't compress well and should be excluded from "scrunching".